# Can't save trained transformer model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, nlp, transformer-model

I have trained on Transformer model but cant save the best model. what is wrong here! Code is running fine and trained.

```
if not os.path.exists("asr-checkpoint"):
    os.makedirs("asr-checkpoint")

checkpoint_path = '/content/asr-checkpoint'
cp_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
    filepath=checkpoint_path,
    monitor='val_loss',
    mode='min',
    save_best_only=True,
    verbose=1
)

print("tf.executing_eagerly():", tf.executing_eagerly())

history = model.fit(
    ds,
    validation_data=val_ds,
    callbacks=[display_cb],
    initial_epoch=0,
    epochs=1
)
```

Comment: did you want to set the callbacks parameter to include your cp_callback?

Comment: I have figured it out to save weights. `model.save_weights('./content/asr-checkpoint/my_checkpoint')`. But can't save the best weight...

Comment: @JonSG Yes. should I provide the `DisplayOutputs` class?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add cp_callback to your fit() call:

```
history = model.fit(
    ds,
    validation_data=val_ds,
    callbacks=[cp_callback, display_cb],
    initial_epoch=0,
    epochs=1
)
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried this, But I think there are some problems with `class DisplayOutputs(keras.callbacks.Callback):`.